# Understanding Hydrostatic Pressure on a Microscopic Scale

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I was reading about the Pascal barrel bursting experiment, and it almost makes sense to me, save for one bit.
I know that pressure corresponds to the number of collisions in the fluid.
So my q is: why does adding water in the tall, narrow pipe in the experiment increase the number of collisions down in the barrel drastically? What is actually going on if we zoom in on a molecule of water in the barrel when we add all the extra water at the top?

Thank you!

Comment: For information - [Pascal's barrel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_law#Pascal's_barrel)

Answer (score 1):

The fluid in the barrel was water and so the pressure is determined by **contact** forces between the water molecules and the barrel molecules.

[image]

Note the downward contact forces on the water due to the barrel with the Newton third law pairing of the upward contact forces on the barrel due to the water.